# Having problem with tree leaves transparency

Tags: modeling, transparency

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7PdiGXbrD0
But when I got to making the leaves transparent, all of the leaves got super bright and weird. It might have something to do with the HDRI I'm using but it looks it should work.

I think it got messed up when I added an Add Shader and a Translucent BSDF.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the node setup of the material for the leaves. And also the settings in the _Material Properties_ tab on the right.

Comment: I think this is what you wanted (I'm very new to blender lol)

Comment: yes, also sorry i didn't add all the nodes.

Comment: I just saw the problem is located somewhere else. The problem is, Steve uses _Cycles_, you are using _Eevee_ so it will probably never look the same like in the tutorial since _Eevee_ is not as good with transparency as _Cycles_. However, you can improve it if you set the _Blend Mode_ to _Alpha Hashed_ instead of _Alpha Blend_. Doesn't look like _Cycles_, but at least it's more transparent. Just be aware that if you don't follow the tutorial, the results are likely to be different.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Thank you!!